# Dynamically generated material UI Radio buttons not clickable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Link to the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-9fwlz

While it seems like this code *should* have checkable radio elements, it does not. Any thoughts on what is broken? This is derived from the material-ui demo snippet, and the only modification is that the radio elements within the RadioGroup are dynamically generated from input props.

```
export default function RadioButtonsGroup(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup
        aria-label="gender"
        name="gender1"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        {props.options.map(([value, readable], index) => (
          <FormControlLabel
            key={index}
            value={value}
            control={<Radio />}
            label={readable}
          />
        ))}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Casual, I'm just an idiot.

```
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
  };
```

the type of `event.target.value` is `string`. My values are `number`s.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  setValue(Number(e.target.value));
}
```

Lovely, that value turning into a `string` and all.

Answer (score 0):

If you value is a number then convert this number into string using toString()

```
<FormControlLabel
key={index}
value={value.toString()}
control={<Radio />}
label={readable}
/>
```